# What should be done in this exercise?

Tags: trigonometry, elementary-set-theory

Determine all the elements of the following sets:

- $A= \{\sin{\frac{n \pi}{4}}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$
- $B= \{\sin{\frac{n \pi}{3}}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Comment: How far did you get in this exercise? Did you manage to do the first one, for example?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Your question, as presented, looks more like an assignment than a request for assistance. The community is here to help you, not to do your homework for you. Please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3583834/edit) to include what you've tried and/or where you got stuck. This information can help answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or talking over your head.

Comment: Ok. But I didn't want that the community do the exercise, I wanted to know what I should do, the instruction, I mean, what the exercise was about

Answer (score 1):

The exercise wants you to list out all values in the given sets. For example, for the first one, determine all values of $\sin{\frac{n \pi}{4}}$ as $n$ ranges over the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$. Note that the sin function is $2\pi$ periodic, that is, for all real numbers $x$, $\sin{(x)}=\sin{(x+2\pi)}$, so try writing out the values for some numbers $n$ and notice if you see an eventual pattern. Perhaps you can prove they begin to repeat and that you have listed all possible values.